# Не работает iconImageHref в Yandex map API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Не работает iconImageHref, просто не отображает значок. Когда убираю строку с ним, стандартный указатель на карте появляется. Перепробовал все пути, абсолютные и относительные, ничего не помогает. Не понятно в чем проблема.

```
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap,
myPlacemark;


function init() {
   myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
     center: [59.93, 30.31],
     zoom: 15,
     controls: []
   });
    myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([59.932951, 30.317412], {}, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://yadi.sk/d/C-6EdK5XxxEhg',
        iconImageSize: [102, 80],
        iconImageOffset: [-34, -80]
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Без остального кода сложно понять, что именно пошло не так, учитывая, что вы использовали разного рода ссылки. Но если ориентироваться на то, что вы предоставили, проблема в том, что вы указываете неверную ссылку на картинку.

Из [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/):

> options.iconImageHref —
>
> Тип: String
>
> URL графического файла иконки

В вашем случае достаточно указать ссылку *напрямую на картинку* т.е. `./image/marker.svg`

Работающий пример можно посмотреть тут: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vk9c1jvt/2/)